# 3D image erosion - Python

Tags: python, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d, image-morphology

I would like o perform erosion on a 3D CT volume using python. I already tried the erosion functions prom SciPy and Scikit-image, but they don't seem to be working properly (neither the dilation). Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import morphology

np_image_data = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(imageData) #Numpy array with CT data
boneMask = np_image_data>=1000
struct = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(3, 1)

# Scipy erosion
erodedMask1 = ndimage.binary_erosion(boneMask.astype(uint), structure=struct, iterations=1)

# Scikit-image erosion
erodedMask2 = morphology.binary_erosion(boneMask.astype(uint), struct)
```

Both of them erode almost the whole image (there are only some voxels left). Are there any suggestions? I tried BinaryErodeImageFilter from SimpleITK, but it is slow and uses a lot of memory.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why the cast of `boneMask` to uint ?

Comment: I was experimenting several input combinations: "True and False", "0 and 1", but none of them works. It is all OK with the `boneMask`.

Comment: What if you try without the custom structure parameter ? It uses a diamond-shaped one instead

Comment: It is still not working, which is strange.. I thought it could be an array problem, but I visualized the `boneMask` and it is correctly generated.

Comment: It is probably data related  : may we peek at your data sources ? If image privacy problem I can show you sample CT images online  to try ?

Comment: I think you are right! I can't provide you my patient data, but I tested the code on the [Visible Human Head](https://bitbucket.org/somada141/pyscience/raw/master/20140908_SurfaceExtraction/Material/vhm_head.zip) and I get the same behaviour. I loaded the CT image (DICOM) with VTK and then converted it to numpy array. If I import the data with SimpleITK and convert it to numpy array everything works fine.

Comment: Why use VTK ? Its syntax is very unpythonic (ugly as hell), and it's a huge dependency for such a small usage ! What about using pydicom, native python library returning directly a numpy array ? If it was the problem I'll formalize it into an answer

Comment: I am using VTK because I'll need to perform surface extraction, registration (ICP), volume rendering, etc... Also, I'd like to create a module for 3D Slicer. But I think I solved the problem. The VTK function vtk.numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy returns a flattened array that should be reshaped (that's what i was doing wrong). My image dimensions are `dims = [512, 512, 166]` (166 slices) and I did a reshape like this: `np_image_data = np_image_data.reshape(dims)`. The conversion should be made the other way around: `np_image_data = np_image_data.reshape(dims[2], dims[1], dims[0])`. Now it works!